# How to plot multiple ACF values on the one graph

Tags: r, plot, time-series, lapply

I've just started using R and would like to use look at the autocorrelation in my data using ACF. My dataframe (GL) looks something like this

```
GL

well    year    month   value  area
684     1994    Jan     8.53    H
684     1994    Feb     8.62    H
684     1994    Mar     8.12    H
684     1994    Apr     8.21    H
684     1995    Jan     8.53    H
684     1995    Feb     8.62    H
684     1995    Mar     8.12    H
684     1995    Apr     8.21    H
684     1996    Jan     8.53    H
684     1996    Feb     8.62    H
684     1996    Mar     8.12    H
684     1996    Apr     8.21    H
101     1994    Jan     8.53    R
101     1994    Feb     8.62    R
101     1994    Mar     8.12    R
101     1994    Apr     8.21    R
101     1995    Jan     8.53    R
101     1995    Feb     8.62    R
101     1995    Mar     8.12    R
101     1995    Apr     8.21    R
101     1996    Jan     8.53    R
101     1996    Feb     8.62    R
101     1996    Mar     8.12    R
101     1996    Apr     8.21    R
```

I would like to:
1. Calculate ACF for each well using lappy or some kind of loop (my actual data set has about 100 wells and three groups)
2. Plot the ACF values (as lines) for each well on one graph for each group (so in this case I would have two acf graphs H & R.

I can use split and lapply to calculate ACF for each well e.g.

```
split <- split(GL$value,GL$well)
test <- lapply(split,acf)
```

But splitting this way doesn't save the area information. If I split like this:

```
split1 <- split(GL,GL$well)
```

Then I don't know how to perform lapply on the values for each well.

Answer (score 1):

As you split the data by well,

```
spl1 <- split(GL, GL$well)
```

the `lapply` would look like this.

```
lapply(spl1, function(x) acf(x$value))
```

We could make this somewhat nicer, though.

When we do the `lapply` by list number we get a "counter" with which we can access the list names to paste together informative titles. With `par(mfrow=c(<rows>, <columns>))` we can set the arrangement of the plots.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
lapply(seq_along(spl1), function(x) acf(spl1[[x]]$value, 
                                        main=paste0("well ", names(spl1)[x], ", ", 
                                                    "area ", unique(spl1[[x]]$area))))
```

***Result***

[image]

This will probably have to be adapted according to how your wells are divided into groups.

<sub>(***As a sidenote:*** Better avoid overwriting function names. You use `split()` and give the result the same name as the function which could induce confusion, both of yourself and of R. Other popular candidates are `data`, `df`, `table`. We can always quickly check with `?` whether the name is "free", e.g. `?df`.)</sub>

---

***Data***

```
# result of `dput(GL)`
GL <- structure(list(well = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("101", "684"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1994", "1995", "1996"
), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Apr", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar"), class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("8.12", 
    "8.21", "8.53", "8.62"), class = "factor"), area = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("H", "R"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with `data.table`:

Let's start with the data (slightly modified from yours, so there will be different values for each `well`):

```
structure(list(well = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("101", "684"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1994", "1995", "1996"), class = "factor"), month = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Apr", "Feb", "Jan", "Mar"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(4.65144120692275, 8.98342372477055, 17.983893298544, 
    15.3687085728161, 8.9577708535362, 7.47583840973675, 16.6564453896135, 11.6158618542831, 23.6109819535632, 14.1604918171652, 11.3882310683839, 20.4579487598967, 3.31275907787494, 22.109053656226, 13.598402187461,     12.3686389743816, 17.9585587936454, 17.3689122993965, 7.38424337399192, 6.93579732463695, 13.2789171519689, 21.2500206897967, 13.5766511948314, 3.58588649751619), area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("H", "R"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Then we create a list for each `well`:

```
GL[, datos := .(list(value)) , by = well]
```

Each row in the `datos` variable will have a list with all the values corresponding to the `well`, so we can drop most of them and keep only the first row of each `well`, as it has all the information already. That is done with `GL[, .SD[1,], by = well]` so the result will be a two-row data table. After that, we can chain another expression that will produce and save each plot:

```
GL[, .SD[1,], by = well][
        , {png(filename = paste0(well, "-", area, ".png"), 
               width = 1600, 
               height = 1600, 
               units = "px", 
               res = 100); 
           plot(a[[1]], main = paste("Well:", well, 
                                     "Area:", area, sep = " "));
           dev.off()}, 
         by = well]
```

Your two plots will be saved in the current directory with names like "684-H.png" and "101-R.png".

Key point here: `data.table` takes **expressions** and not just functions, so it's absolutely possible to produce the plots and save them to any given location.